# Error when configuring a label from a text file

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I would like to configure a label according to its text in the file but nothing happens. Why ?  Here is my code:

```
#function operated by a button 
def add(ligne,labelP):
    if "Diffusion" in ligne:
        labelP.config(text="DiffOk")

#in the Frame "fr"
input = open('precipitation.txt','r+')
for ligne in input:
    ligne=ligne.split()
    labelP=Label(fr,text=ligne)
    labelP.grid(sticky=N+E)

 >>precipitation.txt :
 Diffusion
 Coeff_diffusion-atom1...(cm2/s)    
 Coeff_diffusion-atom2...(cm2/s)    
 Coeff_diffusion-atom3...(cm2/s)    
 ...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

split returns a list, that should be probably the problem, you don't need to split ligne

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't matter and doesn't return any mistakes. Can I directly call "ligne" in the function?

Comment: that was what I was suggesting. Also, the code is not clear, I do not understand why is the add function in it at all, if the file is suppossed to be opened once the add function is called, that part should be indented

Comment: If the code is indented it works well. But I want to make that change when you press a certain button.  Nothing to do that doesn't work... you have no other solution?

Comment: Yes, but it's a very long code... wouldn't there be a method to automatically update one label against another?  For linked 2 labels.  For example: label0=Label(f0,text=´hello')
  labelP.config(label0.update()) but it doesn't work...